# Making One Probability Equal to Another

Tags: probability

I'm playing a turn-based strategy rpg that plays similarly to its tabletop counterpart with slight variations. In this game, the accuracy of your attacks are based on two sets of dice divided into strong dice and standard dice. These dice are 10-sided. A strong die has a success rate of 50% (success if you roll a 6 through 10). A standard die has a success rate of 30% (success if you roll an 8 through 10). My question is, how many standard dice would I need to equal the probability of a strong die and vice versa.

P.S. I'm not too big on math, so please give your explanation in simplified terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you throw two standard dice, they will simultaneously fail in $49\%$ of cases. This is because the probability of two fails is the product of the probability of each fail: $0.7\cdot0.7=0.49$.

So if the relevant criterion is "at least one success", then two standard dice is *almost* equivalent to a single strong die (in fact, two standard dice is marginally stronger than a single strong die).

Comment: I may have made a slight error in my question. How many standard dice does it take to equal the success rate of a strong die? I'm only restating it because I see you've equated the failure rate of the standard dice to the success rate of a strong die.

Comment: @JohnCornelius I don't think I have. Two standard dice failing with probability $49\%$ means they succeed $51\%$ of the time, which is marginally stronger than a single strong die. It's just that the failure rate with multiple dice is a lot easier to calculate than the success rate, so that's what I did. Also, the failure rate of a strong die is equal to the success rate, so which one I'm using shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you ^ ^

Answer (score 0):

If you roll two standard dice each one fails with probability $0.7$.  They both fail with probability $0.7^2=0.49$ which is very close to $0.5$, so if you roll two standard dice and win if either one succeeds it is like rolling a strong die.